# Pyinstaller program: Cannot open self Dev\dist\view\view.exe or archive Dev\dist\view\view.pkg

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I am really struggled with this issue, the error code really means nothing to me.

I have built application with pyinstaller using this command:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Dev> pyinstaller --noconfirm --noupx --log-level=WARN --onedir --add-data="browserRobot.py;." --add-data="ITCrequester.py;." --add-data="sharepoint.ps1;." --add-data="lib;." -d "all" view.py
```

Application is written in Python, mainly based on PyQt5.
After opening an exe file generated by pyinstaller, I am receiving this error:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Dev\dist\view> .\view.exe
[6808] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[6808] LOADER: executable is C:\Users\User\Dev\dist\view\view.exe
[6808] LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\User\Dev\dist\view
[6808] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
[6808] LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\User\Dev\dist\view\view.exe
[6808] LOADER: Cannot open archive: C:\Users\User\Dev\dist\view\view.exe
[6808] LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\User\Dev\dist\view\view.pkg
[6808] LOADER: Cannot open archive: C:\Users\User\Dev\dist\view\view.pkg
[6808] Cannot open self C:\Users\User\Dev\dist\view\view.exe or archive C:\Users\User\Dev\dist\view\view.pkg
```

Even if I try to run it from explorer view or command line with elevated privileges I am still receiving the same error.

Also many missing modules:

```
missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level)
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (conditional), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level)
missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level)
missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), requests.utils (delayed, conditional, optional), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, conditional, optional), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level)
missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass (optional), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level)
missing module named urllib.getproxies_environment - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.proxy_bypass_environment - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.proxy_bypass - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.getproxies - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.urlencode - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.unquote_plus - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.quote_plus - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.unquote - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.quote - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level)
missing module named _dummy_threading - imported by dummy_threading (optional), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), C:\Users\A701923\OneDrive - Atos\Development\IT_Controls_DB_Automation\Onboarding_automation\Dev\view.py (top-level), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
missing module named StringIO - imported by PyQt5.uic.port_v2.string_io (optional), urllib3.packages.six (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named Cookie - imported by requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named cookielib - imported by requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib2 - imported by requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urlparse - imported by requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named simplejson - imported by requests.compat (optional)
missing module named backports - imported by urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname (optional)
missing module named Queue - imported by urllib3.util.queue (conditional)
missing module named brotli - imported by urllib3.util.request (optional), urllib3.response (optional)
missing module named "'urllib3.packages.six.moves.urllib'.parse" - imported by urllib3.request (top-level), urllib3.poolmanager (top-level)
runtime module named urllib3.packages.six.moves - imported by http.client (top-level), urllib3.connectionpool (top-level), urllib3.util.response (top-level), 'urllib3.packages.six.moves.urllib' (top-level), urllib3.response (top-level), urllib3.util.queue (top-level)
missing module named socks - imported by urllib3.contrib.socks (optional)
missing module named cryptography - imported by urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl (top-level), requests (optional)
missing module named 'OpenSSL.crypto' - imported by urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl (delayed)
missing module named 'cryptography.x509' - imported by urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl (delayed, optional)
missing module named 'cryptography.hazmat' - imported by urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl (top-level)
missing module named OpenSSL - imported by urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl (top-level)
missing module named port_v2 - imported by PyQt5.uic.properties (conditional)
missing module named cStringIO - imported by PyQt5.uic.port_v2.string_io (optional)
missing module named copy_reg - imported by cStringIO (top-level)
```

Anyone faced with similar issue ?

Comment: I am adding link to pyinstaller log [link]https://gist.github.com/Kuchtek/96a232bac558db9cfb51754556f64d83[link]
Do anyone have similar situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like I have found solution by myself.

My fault, I didn't choose another name for executable, so it replace some files, which caused my application won't start at all.
Here is my command at the end:

```
pyinstaller -y --add-data "C:/Users/User/Dev/browserRobot.py";"." --add-data "C:/Users/User/Dev/ITCrequester.pyo";"." --add-data "C:/Users/User/Dev/sharepoint.ps1";"." --add-data "C:/Users/User/Dev/lib";"lib/" --add-data "C:/Users/A701923/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5";"PyQt5/" --noupx --log-level DEBUG -n Operation_automation -p C:\Users\A701923\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages;C:\Users\A701923\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36;C:\Users\A701923\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib --debug all  "C:/Users/User/Dev/view.py"
```

The problem was also PyQt itself, so if I joined data folder to application directly, it is running without any errors.